# Escaping minus sign in PHP echo statement

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here: the following is echoing lat-long variables from MySQL, and the longitude variable begins with a minus sign, which prevents the echo statement from reading it and all that follows it. I'm sure there is a way to clean/escape that but just can't work it out.

> echo "
> http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=" . $row['latitude'] . "," .     $row['longitude'] . " target=_new>View in Google Maps";

This is output from a PDO query and testing passing the lat-long into Google Maps.

Comment: Whatever negative value your longitude is, it should not prevent echo from displaying it.

Comment: Then something else must be wrong: when I change the $row to a nbr w/o a minus, it works. urlencode adds a "+" sign in front of the longitude, like this: >http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=44.0083,+-69.8950

Comment: @joucks OK, fixed, and my error was that the DB isn't clean: there are spaces in front of the longitude data! Removing them makes it work.

Comment: ok good to know, good luck for the continuation !

Comment: The coordinates aren't being stored as DECIMAL? Cool.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, it's a link?

Then, use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php) for string.

Answer (score 0):

The minus signs are not a problem.  You may need to `urlencode()` because of the comma, but you need quotes around the URL in the href as well:

```
echo '<br /><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=' 
. urlencode($row['latitude'] . ',' . $row['longitude']) 
. '" target="_new">View in Google Maps</a>';
```